# Listing all httpd accesses

Tags: mysql, php

I have a server with several domains. The server is having a heavy load but I don't know what domain is the guilty one.

Is there a way to list on terminal the load per server? or what servers are using the https and mysqld daemons?

thanks

Comment: Any decent web log analyser will be able to report on this - and on lots of other things that's going on with your web traffic. If you are at all concerned about the way your sites are behaving then you should be constantly capturing and processing data - that way when you know there's a problem you hae the tools to invesigate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure access to `/server-status` page, and enable `ExtendedStatus On`